# Text Adventure language

Tags: programming-languages

I was thinking of creating a text adventure game and after a small google search, I found out that quite a few (simple) text adventure games are created in Prolog.

Why is that?

Comment: Text adventures were the only playable games back in the day and Prolog was one of the few available languages?

Comment: Because Prolog is what young fanatics can learn at third year, being enthusiastic about game development with a long story, but having no time to write a full-scale game.

Comment: Somewhat OT, but [Inform](http://inform7.com/) is probably a more popular choice for writing text adventures nowadays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Exploring Prolog](http://www.amzi.com/articles/prolog_fun.htm):

> As I was writing the utility functions for my game, I happened to go to a Boston Computer Society meeting where the speaker was discussing Prolog. I learned that all of the tools I was building were already integral components of the Prolog language.
>
> Prolog has built-in dynamic memory allocation for storing the state of
> the game that was better than mine because it had an extremely
> flexible way of representing the data. It has a built-in
> pattern-matching capability (unification) that was more general and
> flexible than the pattern-matcher I was implementing, and it had a
> built-in search mechanism (backtracking). Further, the dynamic memory
> allocation didn't just store facts, but stored rules as well, so the
> "data" could embody its own intelligence.
>
> Because of all of this procedural power built into the language, the
> code the programmer writes looks much more declarative. An
> application, such as my adventure game, winds up being reduced to an
> elegant set of logical declarations describing what the program does.
> (Developers often claim up to a 10-fold reduction in code size going
> to Prolog. See for example the PCAI article on KnowledgeWare's use of
> Prolog in the May/June 1993 issue.) For me, this was truly a fun way
> to program, capturing the essence of the joy of programming-building
> logical structures that perform interesting tasks.

Comment: *10-fold reduction of 1993's code.

Comment: Yep.  We were writing code back then too.